# Error on db.SaveChanges(); An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll was not handled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException' occurred in EntityFramework.dll but was not handled in user code
//controller code
 getting data from form collection because of large number of text boxes we get value by using a loop.

And then place it in model class properties of following table TargetManagement_monthly Target
In debugging it gives innerException 
"Invalid object name 'PT.TargetManagement_MonthlyTarget'."}

```
 [HttpPost]
                public ActionResult CreateTarget([Bind(Include =
        "MonthlyTargetID,FinancialYearID,MonthID,dvn_code,itm_ItemCode,ChannelCustomerCode,ChannelCustomerName,IsChannel,TargetQuantity,TargetRevenue,CreatedBy,CreatedDate,UpdatedBy,UpdatedDate")]FormCollection ct)
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i <= 0; i++)
                        {
//Making an object of required table calss.
                            TargetManagement_MonthlyTarget tm = new TargetManagement_MonthlyTarget();

//Now get the formcollection data and Add it to model class properties one by one.
                            tm.FinancialYearID = int.Parse(ct["FinancialYearID"]);
                            tm.dvn_code = ct["dvn_code"];
                            tm.ChannelCustomerCode = ct["ChannelCustomerCode"];
                            tm.ChannelCustomerName = ct["ChannelCustomerName"];
                            if (ct["IsChannel"] == "customer") { tm.IsChannel = false; } else { tm.IsChannel = true; }

                            int count = int.Parse(Request["hfTotalRecordCount"]);
                            string[] arr = new string[count];
                            arr[i] = ct["lstMonthlyTargetDetailModel[" + i + "].itm_ItemCode"];
                            tm.itm_ItemCode = arr[i];
                            for (int j = 1; j <= 1; j++)
                            {
                                int a = int.Parse((Request.Form["lstMonthlyTargetDetailModelColumn[" + j + "].FirstMonthTargetQuantityRow[" + i + "]"]));
                                int b = int.Parse((ct["lstMonthlyTargetDetailModelColumn[" + j + "].FirstMonthTargetRevenueRow[" + i + "]"]));
                                if (a != 0 || a != -1) { tm.TargetQuantity = a; }
                                if (b != 0 || b != -1) { tm.TargetRevenue = b; }
                                tm.MonthID = j;
                                DateTime dt = DateTime.Today; DateTime FDate;
                                var d = String.Format("{0:u}", dt); DateTime.TryParse(d, out FDate);
                                tm.CreatedBy = 16; tm.CreatedDate = FDate; tm.UpdatedBy = 16; tm.UpdatedDate = FDate;
    //MonthlyTargetID is primary key of the table
                                db.TargetManagement_MonthlyTarget.Add(new TargetManagement_MonthlyTarget {FinancialYearID=tm.FinancialYearID,
                                    MonthID=tm.MonthID,dvn_code=tm.dvn_code,
                                    itm_ItemCode=tm.itm_ItemCode,
                                    ChannelCustomerCode=tm.ChannelCustomerCode,
                                    ChannelCustomerName=tm.ChannelCustomerName,
                                    IsChannel=tm.IsChannel,
                                    TargetQuantity=tm.TargetQuantity,
                                    TargetRevenue=tm.TargetRevenue,
                                    CreatedBy=tm.CreatedBy,
                                    CreatedDate=tm.CreatedDate,
                                    UpdatedBy=tm.UpdatedBy,
                                    UpdatedDate=tm.UpdatedDate });

                            }

                        }
                        db.SaveChanges();
                    }

                    return RedirectToAction("Target");
                }
```

Comment: This is error is from sql server and its meaning is there is not such table or view exist on the server so what you can do is debug the code and find what is the connection string of `db` object by having look at `db.ConnectionString` and then check that database with ssms that is there any such a table exist or not.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya yes, i checked the CS and table in ssms and both are fine but the error on db.SaveChanges remain there.plz help me out.